# How to export entire database schema through SSIS Package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

How can i export entire Database Objects including (functions,Triggers,Procedures etc) to another newly created empty Database . I don't want to do through Export or Import or Generate Scripts in SQL Environment  . I just want to do through SSIS Package means in BIDS Environment i need to do?.... Suggest me the best way

Answer (score 0):

Here is a start for you. This is a current project for me. The following script was for copying and then later restoring schema info for any tables we dropped accidentally. This query copies triggers, constraints, indexes (including indexes that span multiple columns), and permissions into a temptable as executable code. So it looks at all the schema info for @fromTable and writes the necessary sql statements for @Totable. There is a commented out portion at the bottom that executes all the queries stored in the temp table.

The only item that is missing here is when there is a foreign key constraint on @fromtable that originates from another table.

A little side knowledge from our project, you cannot add constraints,triggers,indexes with the same name to the same database. You would have to alter the script for that. I also suggest breaking up the query into smaller chunks so you can make them seperate SSIS scripts.

Good luck! (I'm giving you my best stuff here)

```
Declare @Fromtable Varchar(255), @ToTable Varchar(255),@indexcount int, @indexcolumnid    int,@maxindexcount int
set @Fromtable = 'tblname'
set @ToTable = 'tblname'

if object_id('tblTemp') is not null
    Drop table tblTemp

Create table tblTemp (ID int identity, queries varchar(max))

set @indexcount = (select min(si.index_ID) from sys.indexes si inner join sys.tables st
        on st.object_id = si.object_id  where st.name = @Fromtable
        and si.name not like 'PK%')
set @maxindexcount = (select max(si.index_ID) from sys.indexes si inner join sys.tables st
        on st.object_id = si.object_id  where st.name = @Fromtable
        and si.name not like 'PK%')

while (@indexcount <= @maxindexcount)
BEGIN
IF (( select count(si.index_ID) from sys.indexes si inner join sys.tables st
        on st.object_id = si.object_id          inner join sys.columns col
            on si.object_id = col.object_id
        inner join sys.index_columns ic
            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                and col.column_id = ic.column_id    where st.name = @Fromtable
        and si.name not like 'PK%' and si.index_id = @indexcount) = 0)
BEGIN
SET @indexcount += 1

end

else IF (( select count(si.index_ID) from sys.indexes si 
            inner join sys.tables st
        on st.object_id = si.object_id
                    inner join sys.columns col
            on si.object_id = col.object_id
        inner join sys.index_columns ic
            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                and col.column_id = ic.column_id    
        where st.name = @Fromtable
            and si.name not like 'PK%' 
            and si.index_id = @indexcount
            ) = 1)
BEGIN

    insert into tblTemp(queries)
    select  'CREATE ' + si.type_desc + ' INDEX '
            + si.name + ' ON [Dbo].[' + @ToTable + '] ' 
            + '(' + col.name + ') '                                 
    from sys.indexes si
        inner join sys.columns col
            on si.object_id = col.object_id
        inner join sys.index_columns ic
            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                and col.column_id = ic.column_id
        inner join sys.tables st
            on st.object_id = si.object_id
    where st.name = @Fromtable
            and si.name not like 'PK%'
            and si.index_id = @indexcount
SET @indexcount += 1

END


else IF (( select count(si.index_ID) from sys.indexes si inner join sys.tables st
        on st.object_id = si.object_id          inner join     sys.columns col
            on si.object_id = col.object_id
        inner join sys.index_columns ic
            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                and col.column_id = ic.column_id    where st.name = @Fromtable
        and si.name not like 'PK%' and si.index_id = @indexcount) > 1)
    Declare @innerloopcounter int, @BuiltString varchar(max)
    set @innerloopcounter = 2

BEGIN
    SET @indexcolumnid = (SELECT max(ic.index_column_id) from sys.indexes si
                                            inner join sys.columns col
                                                on si.object_id = col.object_id
                                            inner join sys.index_columns ic
                                                on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                                                    and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                                                    and col.column_id = ic.column_id
                                            inner join sys.tables st
                                                on st.object_id = si.object_id
                                        where st.name = @Fromtable
                                                and si.name not like 'PK%'
                                                and si.index_id = @indexcount)
    set @BuiltString = (select  'CREATE ' + si.type_desc + ' INDEX '
                                            + si.name + ' ON [Dbo].[' + @ToTable + '] ' 
                                            + '(' + col.name                                
                                    from sys.indexes si
                                        inner join sys.columns col
                                            on si.object_id = col.object_id
                                        inner join sys.index_columns ic
                                            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                                                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                                                and col.column_id = ic.column_id
                                        inner join sys.tables st
                                            on st.object_id = si.object_id
                                    where st.name = @Fromtable
                                            and si.name not like 'PK%'
                                            and si.index_id = @indexcount
                                            and ic.index_column_id = 1)

    while (@innerloopcounter  <= @indexcolumnid)
    Begin 
        set @BuiltString = @BuiltString + ', ' + (select  col.name                              
                                                    from sys.indexes si
                                                        inner join sys.columns col
                                                            on si.object_id = col.object_id
                                                        inner join sys.index_columns ic
                                                            on ic.object_id = si.object_id
                                                                and ic.index_id = si.index_id
                                                                and col.column_id = ic.column_id
                                                        inner join sys.tables st
                                                            on st.object_id = si.object_id
                                                    where st.name = @Fromtable
                                                            and si.name not like 'PK%'
                                                            and si.index_id = @indexcount
                                                            and ic.index_column_id = @innerloopcounter)


        set @innerloopcounter += 1
    End
    set @BuiltString = @BuiltString + ')'

    insert into tblTemp(queries)
        select @BuiltString 

    SET @indexcount += 1
end
end
 ----------------End indexes, start triggers-------------------------------
 Declare @name int, @count int, @max int, @query Varchar(max)

Create table tempTriggers(ID int identity , trigger_ID int)

Insert into tempTriggers (trigger_ID)
select tr.object_id
FROM sys.triggers AS tr
    INNER JOIN sys.tables AS o ON tr.parent_id = o.object_id
where o.object_id = @name

set @count = 1
set @max = (Select max(ID) from tempTriggers)
set @query = (Select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = (select     trigger_ID from tempTriggers where ID = @count))

while(@count <= @max)
begin
set @query = replace (@query, @FromTable, @ToTable)
insert into tblTemp(Queries)
values (@query)

set @count = @count + 1
set @query = (Select definition from sys.sql_modules where object_id = (select trigger_ID from tempTriggers where ID = @count))
end

drop table tempTriggers
-------------------------end triggers, start permissions-----------------------------

Insert into tblTemp(Queries)

select 'GRANT ' + dp.permission_name collate latin1_general_cs_as
+ ' ON ' + s.name + '.' + @ToTable + ' TO '  + '[' + dpr.name + ']'
FROM sys.database_permissions AS dp
INNER JOIN sys.objects AS o ON dp.major_id=o.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.schemas AS s ON o.schema_id = s.schema_id
INNER JOIN sys.database_principals AS dpr ON dp.grantee_principal_id=dpr.principal_id
WHERE dpr.name NOT IN ('public','guest')
   and o.name = @FromTable

------------------------end permissions, start constraints----------------------------------


Insert into tblTemp(queries)

select 'Alter Table [dbo].[' + @ToTable +'] ADD CONSTRAINT '
    + kc.name +' primary KEY ('
    + col.name +')'

from sys.key_constraints kc
inner join sys.columns col
    on kc.parent_object_id = col.object_id
inner join sys.tables st
    on kc.parent_object_id = st.object_id
where 
st.name = @FromTable
and kc.unique_index_id = col.column_id


Insert into tblTemp(queries)

select 'Alter Table [dbo].[' + @ToTable +'] '
    + 'Add CONSTRAINT [' + dc.name + ']'
    + ' DEFAULT ' + dc.definition + ' '
    + 'FOR [' + col.name + ']' 
from sys.default_constraints dc
inner join sys.columns col
    on dc.parent_object_id = col.object_id
inner join sys.tables st
    on dc.parent_object_id = st.object_id
where 
st.name = @FromTable
and col.column_id = dc.parent_column_id


Insert into tblTemp(queries)

select 'Alter Table [dbo].[' + @ToTable + '] WITH NOCHECK '
    + 'Add CONSTRAINT [' + chk.name + ']'
    + ' CHECK (' + chk.definition + ') '

from sys.check_constraints chk
inner join sys.columns col
    on chk.parent_object_id = col.object_id
inner join sys.tables st
    on chk.parent_object_id = st.object_id
where 
st.name = @FromTable
and col.column_id = chk.parent_column_id

Insert into tblTemp(queries)


select distinct 'Alter Table [dbo].[' + @ToTable + '] '
+ 'ADD FOREIGN KEY ('+ col.name + ') '
+ 'REFERENCES ' + ft.name + ' ('+ fkcol.name + ')'

from sys.foreign_key_columns fkc
inner join sys.tables st
    on fkc.parent_object_id = st.object_id
inner join sys.columns col
    on fkc.parent_object_id = col.object_id
inner join sys.tables ft
    on fkc.referenced_object_id = ft.object_id
inner join sys.columns fkcol
    on ft.object_id = fkcol.object_id

where 
st.name = @FromTable 
and col.column_id = fkc.parent_column_id
and fkc.referenced_column_id = fkcol.column_id

select * from tblTemp

--end of script--execution phase--------------------------------------------------------------------------
/*
declare @count int, @max int, @query Varchar(max)
set @count = 186
set @max = (Select max(ID) from tblTemp)
set @query = (select queries from tblTemp where ID = @count)

while(@count <= @max)
begin

exec(@query)
set @count += 1
set @query = (select queries from tblTempwhere ID = @count)
end

select * from tblTemp

drop table tblTemp
*/
```